# Почему BIOS не видит раздел Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, bios

Имею в наличии материнскую плату Biostar A770E3 и SSD, с записанным на неё Ubuntu Server 18.04.1. Материнская плата не видит раздел "ubuntu" на SSD, при этом сам SSD видит прекрасно (отображается в BIOS и при выборе диска через F12). 
При этом ACER RS880PM-AM видит этот раздел прекрасно и загружает ubuntu с него тоже.
Схожая проблема была чуть больше полугода назад, в тот раз она возникла из-за того, что я записал установочный диск под windows 10, далее на том же компьютере установил уже на SSD и только потом вставил SSD в Biostar. Она решилась проделыванием всего этого процесса на материнской плате Biostar. Сейчас же, почему-то, это не помогает.

Comment: А тип загрузки какой? UEFI или Legacy?

Comment: Ни один не проходит: Native IDE, RAID, AHCI, Legacy IDE, IDE -> AHCI.

Comment: Он спрашивает не про тип контроллера винта, а про тип передачи загрузки от матери к винту.

Comment: @donRumata. аа. Про это без понятия, где посмотреть примерно можно?

Comment: Не поверишь: в настройках биоса. Если не знаешь что это - лучше сначала почитай минимум Википедию: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI , https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS

Comment: @domRumata,  если бы там такой пункт был - я бы об этом знал.

Comment: Я работаю в конторе с 1к+ десктопов. От s775 до s1151. Там ЕСТЬ такой пункт. Либо ты не видишь, либо биос уж очень какой-то специфичный.

Comment: @donRumata s775-s1151? У меня AMD :DDDDD

Биос там AMI, очень старый, 2006 (получается 2.5X-2.6X версия) года и это последняя доступная версия на официальном сайте. Если есть опыт работы с ним - куда тыкнуть чтобы узнать наверняка?

Comment: Я сокеты указал только для показывания разброса по годам. Амд тоже есть, но мало. Могу через фотки экрана.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84070/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-yardal-gedal).